# Xpath to match following sibling in another node

Tags: xpath

This is my html code:

```
<tr>
                <th class="left_cont"><strong>Hello world</strong></th>
                <td class="right_cont padding_left16px"><strong>Hi There</strong></td>
</tr>
```

Now to select the text Hellow world i used.

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Hello world')]
```

Works fine for me.

Now I need to select the text `Hi there` relatively to the hello world text.

I need to do something like this but I can't figure out.

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Hello world')]/following-sibling::strong
```

Doesn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd "strong" element is not actually sibling of the first one. But wrapping "td" elements are siblings. So you could probably use

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Hello world')]/../following-sibling::td/strong
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements with sibling relations are parent of `<strong>` instead of `<strong>` it self, so you can try this way :

```
//*[strong[contains(.,'Hello world')]]/following-sibling::*[strong]/strong
```

Or if you are sure parents involved are always `<th>` and `<td>` :

```
//th[strong[contains(.,'Hello world')]]/following-sibling::td[strong]/strong
```